# Declaring a coercion from a record type

Tags: isabelle

I have a record type

```
record foo =
  main_stuff :: "nat list"
  other_stuff :: "int"
```

If `f` has type `foo`, I would like to be able to have `f` automatically coerced to the `nat list` in the `main_stuff` field, when necessary. For instance, I would like to be able to have expressions like `f ! 5` typecheck as `main_stuff f ! 5`. I've tried using

```
declare [[coercion_enabled]]
declare [[coercion main_stuff]]
```

But the typechecking still fails. My basic question is: are Isabelle coercions compatible with Isabelle record types?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why records should be special w.r.t. coercions, as `foo` is just another type (regardless how it was created). In fact, your example works for me:

```
record foo =
  main_stuff :: "nat list"
  other_stuff :: "int"

abbreviation "x ≡ ⦇ main_stuff = [0], other_stuff = 1 ⦈"

declare [[coercion_enabled]]
declare [[coercion main_stuff]]

term "x ! 0"
```

The last line results in

```
"main_stuff x ! 0"
  :: "nat"
```

But also

```
term "(f :: foo) ! 5"
```

works as expected. Maybe in your example `f` did not have the correct type for some reason?